# Python Pandas: Selecting previous row of matching row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

Say I have a dataframe with multiple columns and a time series index.

For just one of these columns, I need to replace the NaN immediately before a non-NaN value with a value from another column.

To illustrate this, the below

`2003-10-24 02:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 03:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 04:00:00    0.001
2003-10-24 05:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 06:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 07:00:00    0.006
2003-10-24 08:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 09:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 10:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 11:00:00    0.004`

would become

`2003-10-24 02:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 03:00:00    0.002
2003-10-24 04:00:00    0.001
2003-10-24 05:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 06:00:00    0.001
2003-10-24 07:00:00    0.006
2003-10-24 08:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 09:00:00      NaN
2003-10-24 10:00:00    0.003
2003-10-24 11:00:00    0.004`

For example purposes, the column with replacement data is

`2003-10-24 02:00:00    0.001
2003-10-24 03:00:00    0.002
2003-10-24 04:00:00    0.001
2003-10-24 05:00:00    0.015
2003-10-24 06:00:00    0.001
2003-10-24 07:00:00    0.006
2003-10-24 08:00:00    0.005
2003-10-24 09:00:00    0.002
2003-10-24 10:00:00    0.003
2003-10-24 11:00:00    0.004`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the prettiest approach in the world but here goes. Start by finding the integer indices of desired data replacement `ind`. In the following example I am replacing values of `df["col1"]` with `df["col2"]`

```
import numpy as np

ind = np.where( df.col1.isnull() & df.col1.shift(-1).notnull() )

df.loc[df.index[ind], "col1"] = df.loc[df.index[ind], "col2"]
```

Is this what you wanted?